# Xtify with Worklight 6.2 - sample app does not receive any push notification

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ibm-mobilefirst, xtify

We have successfully tried the native iOS version of Xtify. Right now, we want to try to integrate the Xtify with Worklight 6.2. We have followed the steps from this link: https://developer.ibm.com/push/docs/ibm-mobile-push-notification/ibm-worklight/

The SDK we downloaded are the following:

- http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/Download+IBM+Push+Notification+SDK+for+Apple+iOS+and+Android+for+IBM+Worklight+6.2
- https://developer.ibm.com/push/docs/ibm-mobile-push-notification/sdks/download-ibm-push-notification-sdk-ios-alternate-2/

So far, we have successfully launched the application and Xtify was able to detect our device with its XID. However, the application could not receive any notification from the Xtify when we tried to create a Push Point.

Are we missing a step?

Notes:
We are using Xcode 6 for the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WL 6.2 sample app already includes SDK. You don't need to download additional SDK. Also, WL 6.2 uses the main SDK not the alternative, although you could use an alternative SDK if you need to.

If your sample app registered with Xtify, and you get an XID, you should see your registration (with normal token) on [Xtify Console](https://console.xtify.com/testing) and you can try to send simple notification from that page.

If you still don't get the simple push, you can check the FAQ in [I didn't receive a push](http://developer.xtify.com/display/sdk/IBM+Push+Notification+SDK+for+Apple+iOS+and+APNS+Push+FAQ#IBMPushNotificationSDKforAppleiOSandAPNSPushFAQ-Ididntreceiveapush%C2%A0)